# Edit content of footer in wordpress via admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer

I am trying to change the content of my footer in a wordpress theme. The contents doesn't seem to come from the footer.php file. I need to change the contact information in the footer. Does anyone has any idea how to do that using wp-admin? This is how my footer.php looks right now in my current theme:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Your Inspiration Themes
 * 
 * In this files there is a collection of a functions useful for the core
 * of the framework.   
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Your Inspiration Themes
 * @author Your Inspiration Themes Team <info@yithemes.com>
 *
 * This source file is subject to the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE (GPL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
 */
?>                         

            <?php
            /**
             * @see yit_footer
             */
            do_action( 'yit_footer') ?>

        </div>
        <!-- END WRAPPER -->
        <?php do_action( 'yit_after_wrapper' ) ?>        

    </div>
    <!-- END BG SHADOW -->

    <?php wp_footer() ?> 

</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open **function.php** or any file which having theme function and find `wp_footer()` to change the footer content.